# I want to count total yes against an id in a particular row not a column

Tags: laravel

[image]

I want to sum total yes in a row like following

| id | user_id | eligible | asset | requirement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | yes | no | yes |
| 2 | 1 | yes | yes | yes |
| 3 | 2 | no | yes | no |

Result should be following:

| user_id | yes_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is a debugging community not a code writing service. Please provide what you have tried so far and details of where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that table as `Items`.

**User model**

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
$users = User::withCount([
        'items as items_eligible_yes_count' => fn($q) => $q->where('eligible', 'yes'),
        'items as items_asset_yes_count' => fn($q) => $q->where('asset', 'yes'),
        'items as items_requirement_yes_count' => fn($q) => $q->where('requirement', 'yes'),
    ])
    ->get();
```

**View**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>user_id</th>
            <th>yes_count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->items_eligible_yes_count + $user->items_asset_yes_count + $user->items_requirement_yes_count }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```